# Use `eslint` without providing files on the command line?

Tags: javascript, eslint

```json
"lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.json --fix src/**/*.ts test/**/*.ts *.ts",
"lint:prod": "eslint -c .eslintrc.prod.json --fix src/**/*.ts test/**/*.ts *.ts",
```

Note the duplicative paths in these NPM scripts. And there is one more that look pretty much the same in the `lint-staged` config.

It seems I cannot omit the paths, and have eslint use its config file (`.eslintrc.json`) to find the files to lint:

```json
  "overrides": [
    {
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
      ],
      "files": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "test/**/*.ts",
        "*.ts"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

At least, with that config in place, and running `npx eslint -c .eslintrc.json`, no files are checked. Adding the paths to the command line does check the files.

I guess `overrides[].files` only tells the related parser which files to look at, but not eslint itself.

Is it not supported to just use the config file to figure out which files to check?

Comment: Which file contains that second JSON snippet?

Comment: Sorry, it's `.eslintrc.json`. Updated above.

Comment: You have different lint configurations for development and production? What’s the story there? :D

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of npm scripts themselves and have a script that does "the shared bits", and then invoke that with argument passing (using `--`) to make it do "the bits that are different":

```json
{
  "scripts":  {
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts test/**/*.ts *.ts\" --fix",
    "lint:dev": "npm run lint -- -c .eslintrc.json",
    "lint:prod": "npm run lint -- -c .eslintrc.prod.json"
  }
}
```

(Also note the quotes around the glob, which eslint [says is necessary](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#run-the-cli), and that they're double quotes rather than single quotes, to make sure things work on every OS. Single quotes will break on Windows)

Comment: That's assuming OP is using `npm` and not some other runner like `yarn`, `pnpm`, etc

Comment: Tailor as appropriate. They're using `npx`, so in absence of further details, probably also `npm`.

Comment: FYI Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter works better with the `lang-` prefix (I noticed you reverted that). Using `\`\`\`json` looks up the assigned language for the [tag:json] tag whereas `\`\`\`lang-json` avoids the lookup

Comment: Ah, I thought that only applied to the old `<!-- lang` concept, with the markdown fences using github's flavour of syntax highlighting. Good to know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I assume, then, that there is no way to omit the paths from the command line args? This is a decent workaround, but it sure would be nice to be able to simply do `eslint -c <path_to_config>` and have all the config be ... in the config.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. There's no `input` or `include` etc that you can add to the eslint config. That said, the config is for "configuring the tool", and saying which files to apply things to is not "configuration" in that sense. Plus, and that's the biggest one: the only one who's bothered is the human (i.e. you) but the human isn't running these scripts. You just add your dev linting to `npm test` and you prod linting to a CI task, and then you never look at it again.

Comment: "the only one who's bothered is the human" -- sure, but you could say that about a lot of things. In this case, having to maintain multiple lists of paths just seems unnecessary. Your suggestion will do the trick to shorten that from 3 lists to 2. Thanks.

Comment: You could, but in this case it's one of those "configure once, never touch or see again" issues, so it's a little more apt than in most cases. Unlike your code, or even environment configs or the like, you're not going to be looking at your package.json file tens of times in a day. You're just going to click the run button, or maybe type `npm run test`. Neither of those requires you to ever see, let alone type, anything relating to those linting paths.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a folder to lint on the command line, `eslint` uses the `files` property from the overrides in the configuration file to find files to lint in that folder. See eslint documentation about [specifying target files to lint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#specifying-target-files-to-lint).

So instead of `npx eslint -c .eslintrc.json` you need to run `npx eslint -c .eslintrc.json .` to try this out. The only difference is the `.` at the end: the folder to lint.

And in your `package.json` scripts you probably want something like:

```json
"lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.json --fix .",
"lint:prod": "eslint -c .eslintrc.prod.json --fix .",
```

While it is annoying to put the `.` there, it does not create a maintenance burden because it will not change in the future. The actual configuration about which files to lint is maintained only once in the configuration file.